# Detecting Device for website

Tags: flash, ipad, web, device

I'm creating a website with Flash embedded into it. I understand that iPads do not support flash. I also have a non-flash version ready only to be used for iPad users. How do I detect the end user's device and redirect them to the version directly ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're checking this from the website, you could use the following JavaScript code;

```
function isiPad() {
    return (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPad") != -1);
}
```

So, for example, you could add something like this to `onload`
`if(isiPad()) window.location = "http://mysite.com/ipad";`

[Detect iPad users using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617638/detect-ipad-users-using-jquery)