# How do I detect a mobile device (iPhone, iPad etc), using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [best way to detect handheld device in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery)

Hi All,

I have a link on my website for the Terms & Conditions in the footer...when I click this link it brings up a modal window containing the Terms & Conditions. The problem is that the scroller doesnt show up in the modal window when a mobile device is present & the user cannot read the full text.

Is there a way, when the user clicks the link, a script then detects if a mobile device is present...then redirects to a static version of the Terms & Conditions page?

I would be grateful if someone has a snippet of JQuery/JavaScript that does this as I'm a beginner at both JQuery and JavaScript. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery

Comment: @Scott - Thanks for that. Is there a similar way of detecting iPad's and mobile tablets etc?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617638/detect-ipad-users-using-jquery