# How to execute a javaScript function only when using an IPhone / IPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad, detection

I want to execute a javascript function, only if the user is using an IPad / IPhone.

Something like this:

```
var checkifipadoriphone = true; //or false
if(checkifipadoriphone){
    executesomefuntion();
}
```

How does one do this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect iPad users using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617638/detect-ipad-users-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function isiPhone(){
    return (
        //Detect iPhone
    //var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) ||
        //Detect iPod
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPad") != -1)
    );
}

if(isiPhone()){
    executesomefuntion();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp) to see if you can use it to extract  the browser type from the navigator object.