# Remove links to javascript if using an iPad

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad

How would I remove all links to javascript if someone is viewing a site from an iPad.

For Example the web version would have links in the head to js files for various things on the site.

But I would want the iPad version to remove or ignore these links so no js was being linked to.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Check if this link helps http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You could load them on the client side, checking browser features, after page load.

They could also be written dynamically sever side by checking the user agent.

Answer (score 0):

Detect the browser using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617638/detect-ipad-users-using-jquery) and write your code to make use of the `isiPad` variable. It would be easier to do than removing code tags from html *(at least without jQuery)*.