# Hide element when using iOS devices?

Tags: javascript

I want to check if user is using iPhone/iPad/iPod and if true, hide element.

How to do it using javascript?

Tried to do it like this: [Hide HTML element if user is on an iOS device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928091/hide-html-element-if-user-is-on-an-ios-device)

But it didnt work, i put the code in my controller in AngularJS

Code I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var iOS = false,
  p = navigator.platform;
  if( p === 'iPad' || p === 'iPhone' || p === 'iPod' ) {
     iOS = true;
  }
  if (iOS === false) {
     $("input[type=button]").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: You really need to post some code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @Stuart I dont have any code for it, i have simple div with a class that I want to hide if the device is iOS. I'll copy the code I tried from the prev answer as edit in my question.

Comment: "i put the code in my controller in AngularJS" - post the code of your controller with this code you tried.

Comment: @Stuart my controller has 546 lines of code :)

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(navigator.platform)`?

Comment: @BrunoPeres it logs Win32, but my element is not hidden on iPhone

Comment: Are you sure that the output is "iPhone" in iPhone devices?

Comment: @BrunoPeres No I am not, thats why I am asking since I tried the code from another thread :/

Comment: @BrunoPeres I am testing the app on iPhone, using ngrok. It alerts iPhone

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check if user is using iPhone/iPad/iPod **and if true, hide
>   element**.

But in the code shown you are testing if `iOS` variable is `false`! You should change the test to `if (iOS === true)`.

*Tip: Also, you can do some improvements in your code and make it more elegant. For example:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    var appleDevices = ['iPad', 'iPhone', 'iPod'];

    if (appleDevices.indexOf(navigator.platform) > -1) {
        $("input[type=button]").hide();
    }

});
```

This code does the same thing as the one posted by you, but using an array and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). That is: hide `input[type=button]` when the value of `navigator.platform` is an element of the `appleDevices` array.