# How can I set a variable in $rootscope to show if a browser is running on an iPad?

Tags: angularjs

I know there are some libraries that can do this but I would like to do something as simple as possible and I didn't see any examples that were for an AngularJS app. The problem is I do not know where to start.

Can someone give me some advice or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.isIpad = /ipad/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="test">
  <h1>is iPad? <span ng-bind="isIpad | json"></span></h1>
</section>
```

---

if you want to have a more robust solution, have a look here [Detect iPad users using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617638/detect-ipad-users-using-jquery)

Comment: I will test out and test.  iPad not available in front of me right now so I'll check out later. Thanks very much