# JQuery for Detecting iOS only working on some versions

Tags: jquery, ios

I'm hoping someone can assist me. I have the following in my jQuery to detect iOS so I can hide a preloader. It only works on some and I'm not sure why. The abbreviated version is here:

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
        var iOS = false,
        p = navigator.platform;
        if (p === 'iPad' || p === 'iPhone' || p === 'iPod') {
            iOS = true;
        }
        if (iOS) {
            $('#preloader').hide();
        }
   else {
            // hide preloader after loaded
            jQuery('#preloader').delay(300).fadeOut(300);
        }
});
```

The preloader is a black screen that fades away and was not working across all iOS devices. So I thought hiding would be the way to go. However, I am unable to even target iOS across versions.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: It even works across version 8.3 but not iPad Mini and yes on iPad Air. Really strange.

Comment: Maybe this thread could be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617638/detect-ipad-users-using-jquery

Comment: Just tried it and still won't hide the preloader. On browserstack.com/responsive for testing across devices/OS.