# How make media queries, one that includes the iPad pro and one that excludes it for desktop?

Tags: html, css, ipad, media-queries

The iPad Pro is in a width that crosses into desktop widths - 1366px. There are a lot of smaller laptops now that fit the same width as the iPad Pro (the 11 and 13 inch laptops).

On the iPad Pro, I want to show things like a hamburger menu, but on the desktops, I want navigation with mouseovers.

Before the iPad Pro, I could make the cutoff be 1024 px wide, but now there's cross-over.

I need both a media query that includes it (so it shows the mobile landscape view) and one that excludes it (so desktops show only when not ipad Pro).

I think this one includes it properly:

```
<!-- Put on multiple lines for readability -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen 
     and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
     and (max-device-width: 1366px) 
     and (orientation: landscape) 
     and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)"                
     href="/css/desktop.css" />
```

But I can't figure out how to make a desktop media query that will *exclude* the iPad Pro *and* include all desktops from 1024px and larger. Is this possible? What would it be?

Comment: Why not make your navigation work with both mouseover and click/tap?

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't want the hamburger to even show on small desktops, and I *do* want it to show on iPad Pro.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good attempt, but you can't be sure if you don't test it on those devices. I think most reliable way to do this is using script like the one on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4617648/1729641

You can for example add a class to `body` with JavaScript:

```
document.body.className += (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null) ? ' ipad' : '';
```

If you use JQuery:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null) {
    $(body).addClass('ipad');
}
```

If your goal is to avoid downloading this style on another device, you can load it with AJAX. It's *unpure*, I know.